# How to properly scraping filtered content using XPath Query to Google Sheet?

Tags: xpath, google-sheets-formula

So, this is about a content from a website which I want to get and put it in my Google Sheets, but I'm having difficulty understanding the class of the content.

target link: https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/?symbol=XAU=

This number is what I want to get from. [Picture 1: The part which i want to **scrape**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzGv0.png)

And this is what the code looks like in inspector. [Picture 2: The code shown in inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcUDv.png)

The target is inside a span attribute but the span attribute looks very difficult to me, so I tried to simplify it using this line of code here `=IMPORTXML("https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/?symbol=XAU=","//table[@class='quote-horizontal regular']//tr/td/span")`
[Picture 3: List is shown when putting the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZLpt.png)

After some tries, I am able to get the right target, but it confuse me, Im using this code `=IMPORTXML("https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/?symbol=XAU=","//table[@class='quote-horizontal regular']//tr/td/span[@class='last original'][1]")`
[Picture 4: The right target is shown when the xpath query is more specified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTChx.png)
As what you can see in 2nd Picture, 'last original' is not really the full name of the class, when I put the 'last original ng-binding' instead it gave me an error saying `imported content is empty`

So, correct me if my code is wrong, or accidental worked out somehow because there's another correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Modified formula 1:

When the name of class is `last original` and `last original ng-binding`, how about the following xpath and formula?

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//span[contains(@class,'last original')][1]")
```

- In this case, the URL of `https://www.cnbc.com/quotes/?symbol=XAU=` is put in the cell "A1".
- In this case, `//span[contains(@class,'last original')][1]` is used as the xpath. The value of `span` that the name of class includes `last original` is retrieved. So `last original` and `last original ng-binding` can be used.

#### Modified formula2:

As other xpath, how about the following xpath and formula?

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//meta[@itemprop='price']/@content")
```

- It seems that the value is included in the metadata. So this sample retrieves the value from the metadata.

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)

Comment: the 1st formula seems like the shortened version of my code, so I can understand it very clearly, however the 2nd one, I dont know whats meta used for here, but the itemprop is refering to the browser bar title, which has a "late" result of the actual number. and I dont know where you get that 'price' word from, but it actually works. (ah nevermind, i found the meta itemprop with content price) so can you explain whats this part about(like the body? the prolog or what?) im sorry im newb in xml. hovering the inspector does not pointing to anywhere.

Comment: @Ahiung Lim Thank you for replying. About the modified formula 2, when I saw the HTML, I found `<meta itemprop="price" content="###" />` below `<!--structured data -->`. In my environment, when HTML source is confirmed using the browser, it can be seen. If this meta data is the universal, it might be able to be used for your situation. So I proposed this xpath as 2nd one. About `meta`, you can see the document at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta). If this my reply is not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Ahiung Lim Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

To complete @Tanaike's answer, two alternatives :

```
=IMPORTXML(B2;"//span[@class='year high']")
```

"Year high" seems always equal to the current stock index value.

Or, with value retrieved from the `script` element :

```
=IMPORTXML(B2;"substring-before(substring-after(//script[contains(.,'modApi')],'""last\"":\""'),'\')")
```

Note : since I'm based in Europe, you need to replace `;` with `,` in the formulas.

Comment: thanks for adding more variant in order to get those numbers, seems like so many ways to do it, ill just pick the simplest one.